# Unprocessable Entity: The following relationship fields were provided as attributes

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to set the value of a taxonomy term entity reference field with a POST operation in JSON:API.

```
const data = {
  data: {
    type: 'node--page',
    attributes: {
      field_text: {
        value: `${values.textFieldValue}`,
        format: 'basic_html',
      },
      field_ref_term: {
        type: 'taxonomy-term--my-vocabulary',
        id: '9ca0cdc7-384c-4aa4-8ce9-d6c97fc2f44b',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

However, that gives me this error:

> Unprocessable Entity: The following relationship fields were provided
> as attributes: [ field_ref_term ]

What am I supposed to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, the entity reference has to be set in **relationships**, not **attributes**.

[The documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/creating-new-resources-post) gives this example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "node--article",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Article by admin",
      "body": {
        "value": "Custom value",
        "format": "plain_text"
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "uid": {
        "data": {
          "type": "user--user",
          "id": "{{UUID of user 1}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, the author of the node is set using the relationship of `uid`.  However, it wasn't immediately clear to me how to set the entity reference field.

It turns out to be quite easy:

```
const data = {
  data: {
    type: 'node--page',
    attributes: {
      field_text: {
        value: `${values.textFieldValue}`,
        format: 'basic_html',
      },
    },
    relationships: {
      field_ref_term: {
        data: {
          type: 'taxonomy-term--my-vocabulary',
          id: '9fa0cdc7-384c-4aa4-8ce9-d6c97fc2f44b',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The key for the relationship is the machine name of the entity reference field.